# The 'Tags' input box overflows its parent box until the graph loads on the trends page

Tags: bug, trends

The tags' input box on the [trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends) page overflows outside its parent box until the graph on the right loads. Once the graph has loaded, however, it pops back into place...

> [image]

> [image]

Seen on Firefox 104.0.2 (64-bit) and Chrome Version 105.0.5195.125 (Official Build) (64-bit).